# Is it worth regularly publishing in unknown business & management journals?

Tags: publications, journals, promotion

I notice some business & management full professors regularly publish in unknown or low rank journals. Yet I have previously been advised to be very careful where I publish. Is there value in the 'Stack 'em high' method in the Business & Management field?

Comment: There are not many business school faculty on this site.  Consider that when evaluating answers.

Comment: The rank of 'full professor' is not uniform across countries and universities.  I know of many full professors who do not know how to do research.  Indeed, some have no PhD degree.

Answer (score -1):

For someone who already has a solid academic record publishing in non-traditional, but more visible, venues can be a way to get some recognition in the wider world - outside academia. But I doubt that it has a lot of effect on the things that lead to an academic reputation.

Even in other fields, there are "public scholars" who spend time and effort on making the results of research known to non-academics whose practice might benefit from it. Think of it as a public service, not an academic reputation builder.

In physics, for example, Carl Sagan was such a public scholar, even though he had a solid academic reputation as well. In fact, it was that academic reputation that gave him credibility in the larger world.

For a young scholar, however, it may mean less.

Comment: Publishing in unknown journals does not give you recognition, nor does it reach non-academics.